# Android ParseQueryAdapter Fatal error

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

Has anybody seen this fatal error when using `ParseQueryAdapter` for Android `ListView`. I can't give any details because it just crashes my app. I can't put a breakpoint because the error is in parse itself.

Any help on how I can figure out this problem is greatly appreciated.

```
03-25 23:54:51.743  29533-29533/com.johamcruz.Balln E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter$3.done(ParseQueryAdapter.java:384)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
        at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:940)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace specifically says Invalid index 1, size is 1.

The arraylist you are using has a size of 1.  That location is myindex[0].  Using an index of 1, myindex[1] is an error because there is no data in that location.

Either your arraylist reference is bad or your initialization of the arraylist did not work.

Comment: My issue is within parse framework for android. I cant really modify parsequery adapter to fix the problem.